# Double auth with requests

Tags: python, python-requests, locust

I'm using Locust (which uses Requests) to do page load tests. The page has a popup requesting username and password to access the page and there is a standard login page.

I'm using the `client.auth` to authenticate the first time (on the popup) to open the page and send data on the POST request to login the account.

The problem is that Locust never displays a failure, even when I skip the second authentication. In other words, if I do the client.auth authentication I can GET any page (even the ones for which authentication is needed, and I skip the second authentication) and Locust does not display a 401 error. So I'm doing something wrong here.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
def on_start(self):
    self.login()

def login(self):
    # Set basic auth credentials
    if BASIC_AUTH_CREDENTIALS:
        self.client.auth = BASIC_AUTH_CREDENTIALS

    headers = {
        'referer': 'http://myreferer.com'
    }
    data = {
        'username': 'John',
        'password': 'Doe',
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '123456712345671234567'
    }

    r = self.client.post('/login', data=data, headers=headers)

@task
def progress(self):
    self.client.get("/needed/authorization")
```

What I want is to measure the time it takes a page to load when a number of users try to load it. I have a couple of pages that I measure this on, one that loads fast the other much slower, but the test displays the same values for both. I think that Locust's simulated users get redirected to the login page every time and therefor they have the same response time and don't report a 401 or 404, or any error for that matter.

Please help me do this properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testing the login required pages you should send loged-in user's info (cookie) in the header.

```
class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

cookie = ""

def on_start(self):
    self.cookie = self.get_user_cookie()

def get_user_cookie(self):
    # Set basic auth credentials
    if BASIC_AUTH_CREDENTIALS:
        self.client.auth = BASIC_AUTH_CREDENTIALS

    headers = {
        'referer': 'http://myreferer.com'
    }
    data = {
        'username': 'John',
        'password': 'Doe',
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '123456712345671234567'
    }

    r = self.client.post('/login', data=data, headers=headers)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.request.headers['Cookie']
    else:
        print "User cannot login"

@task
def progress(self):
    self.client.get("/needed/authorization", headers = {"Cookie": self.cookie})
```